# Making SOAP call to a WSDL with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, webservice-client, ref

https://www.ticimax.com/dokumanlar/webservis.pdf

Ticimax is an e-commerce software in Turkey. I'm trying to create products by using their webservice for one of my clients. I've used all of their webservice methods. But i'm stuck with their product creation method "**SaveUrun**". Because this method has only one thing different from other methods. This method accepts a parameter as **ref**

SaveUrun method is in the document from page 7 to page 9.

If you look at page 9, you will see this line at the end of the method definitions:

```
urunServis.SaveUrun("U15saQ48dW453X1cA", ref urunKartlari, ukAyar, varyasyonAyar);
```

urunKartlari is passed as ref.

What is ref? What is it stands for? What is the equivalent of it in PHP? How can i make my code work? Can you please help me?

This is what i get when i make the SOAP call:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Here is my example code:

```
<?php

$ticimax = new SoapClient("http://www.CLIENTDOMAIN.com/Servis/UrunServis.svc?wsdl");

$kategoriler = array();

$urunResimleri = array();

$varyasyonlar = array(
   array(
      "ID" => 0,
      "Aktif" => false,
      "AlisFiyati" => 10,
      "Barkod" => "",
      "Desi" => 1,
      "KargoUcreti" => 0,
      "KdvDahil" => true,
      "KdvOrani" => 8,
      "Ozellikler" => array(
                     array(
                        "Tanim" => "Numara",
                        "Deger" => 38
                     ),
                     array(
                        "Tanim" => "Renk",
                        "Deger" => "Mavi"
                     )
                  ),
      "ParaBirimiID" => 1,
      "Resimler" => array(),
      "SatisFiyati" => 100,
      "StokAdedi" => 15,
      "StokKodu" => ""
   ),
   array(
      "ID" => 0,
      "Aktif" => false,
      "AlisFiyati" => 10,
      "Barkod" => "",
      "Desi" => 1,
      "KargoUcreti" => 0,
      "KdvDahil" => true,
      "KdvOrani" => 8,
      "Ozellikler" => array(
                     array(
                        "Tanim" => "Numara",
                        "Deger" => 40
                     ),
                     array(
                        "Tanim" => "Renk",
                        "Deger" => "Mavi"
                     )
                  ),
      "ParaBirimiID" => 1,
      "Resimler" => array(),
      "SatisFiyati" => 100,
      "StokAdedi" => 15,
      "StokKodu" => ""
   )
);

$urunKarti = array(
   "ID" => 0,
   "Aktif" => false,
   "UrunAdi" => "Test ürün adı",
   "Aciklama" => "Test ürün açıklama",
   "AnaKategori" => "İç Giyim",
   "AnaKategoriID" => 1,
   "Kategoriler" => $kategoriler,
   "MarkaID" => 1,
   "TedarikciID" => 1,
   "Resimler" => $urunResimleri,
   "SatisBirimi" => "Adet",
   "UcretsizKargo" => false,
   "OnYazi" => "Test ürün önyazı",
   "PuanDeger" => 12,
   "SeoAnahtarKelime" => "",
   "SeoSayfaAciklama" => "",
   "SeoSayfaBaslik" => "",
   "Varyasyonlar" => $varyasyonlar,
   "Vitrin" => false,
   "YeniUrun" => false
);

$params = array(
   array(
      "UyeKodu" => WEBSERVICE_PASSWORD,
      "UrunKartlari" => $urunKarti,
      "ukAyar" => array(
         "AciklamaGuncelle" => true,
         "AktifGuncelle" => true,
         "FBStoreGosterGuncelle" => false,
         "FirsatUrunuGuncelle" => true,
         "KategoriGuncelle" => false,
         "MaksTaksitSayisiGuncelle" => false,
         "MarkaGuncelle" => false,
         "OnYaziGuncelle" => false,
         "ParaPuanGuncelle" => true,
         "SatisBirimiGuncelle" => false,
         "SeoAnahtarKelimeGuncelle" => false,
         "SeoSayfaAciklamaGuncelle" => false,
         "SeoSayfaBaslikGuncelle" => false,
         "TedarikciGuncelle" => false,
         "UcretsizKargoGuncelle" => true,
         "UrunAdiGuncelle" => true,
         "UrunResimGuncelle" => false,
         "VitrinGuncelle" => false,
         "YeniUrunGuncelle" => true
      ),
      "vAyar" => array(
         "AktifGuncelle" => false,
         "AlisFiyatiGuncelle" => true,
         "BarkodGuncelle" => false,
         "IndirimliFiyatiGuncelle" => true,
         "KargoUcretiGuncelle" => false,
         "KargoAgirligiGuncelle" => true,
         "ParaBirimiGuncelle" => false,
         "PiyasaFiyatiGuncelle" => true,
         "SatisFiyatiGuncelle" => false,
         "StokAdediGuncelle" => true,
         "UyeTipiFiyat1Guncelle" => false,
         "UyeTipiFiyat2Guncelle" => true,
         "UyeTipiFiyat3Guncelle" => false,
         "UyeTipiFiyat4Guncelle" => true,
         "UyeTipiFiyat5Guncelle" => false,
         "TedarikciKodunaGoreGuncelle" => false

      )
   )
);

try{

   print_r($ticimax->__soapCall("SaveUrun", $params));


}
catch(Exception $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Can you please fix my code?

Comment: I don't see anything called `source` in there. Also you should be able to do `$ticimax->SaveUrun($params)` as the internal `__soapCall` method isn't needed when you have a WSDL.

Comment: And what does "this is what I get" mean? From the server? From your PHP code?

Comment: @miken32 It means i get this exception error when i execute the code.

Comment: @miken32 is it the reason i can't make this call? I can use any other method in that webservice except for this one.

Answer (score 0):

`UyeKodu` `UrunKartlari` fields in Params **array** must be `uyeKodu` `urunKartlari`